# Image Uploading in C# Emgu Open CV not working, giving an Exception every time I try and load

Tags: c#, image, opencv, emgucv

Trying to upload an image into my image box and keep getting an exception, that breaks the code any ideas? (Type initialized Exception). This is the first time I have used the Emgu like this

```
       private void btnload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                input = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName).Resize(500, 500,INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC, false);
                imageBox1.Image = input;
                gray = input.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
            }
            btnSet.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Post the full error please

Comment: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Trace surely has more info. Usually the most common problems are:

- **EMGU and OpenCV DLL verisons:** Check if you're using the correct 32 or 64 bit DLL's version like your project.
- **EMGU version agains OpenCV version**: Check the Stack Trace Message, you might find something saying *"Unable to load DLL 'some DLL'"*

  - If this is the case, check if the DLL's next to your EXE have the same version (number at the end of the file name)
- **OpenCV DLL's Missing**: Do not forget to copy OpenCV DLL's to the same folder of the EXE

Hope this helps, Cheers